# How to select the n th row in every field?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1eRe.png)I have a pivot table with lots of rows and fields in it, so I want to select/copy the 1st row of every field

[image]

I want to select the 1st row(County) of every State.

Comment: Hi @Rustam Ibrahimli,, the attached screen shot doesn't  clears the issue,, counties in Pivot Table doesn't match with other data above & below so better share some original data, has been used to create PT,, & is there any criteria to copy count data,, and where to copy,, in same sheet,,, or new sheet/WB !! I think the basic issue is select Nth row !!

Comment: @RajeshS hi, the data is original. My question is how select every 1st county from each state row. For example: The row that expanded is the counties of Massachusetts( MA ) and Plymouth is the county with the highest with Domestic Migration Rate. So I want to choose this county and also other counties with the highest DMR in other states. Not just clicking one by one, if there is any function that can do automatically, please let me know.

Comment: Hi @Rustam Ibrahimli,, you want this solution within Pivot Table,, or out of that,,  as simple table? And please share the Table/Range which has been used to create PT.

Comment: @RajeshS added the original table too, within PivotTable or not just ned a sollution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you got your data from [here](https://www.governing.com/gov-data/census/2017-county-migration-rates-population-estimates.html) - since that's quoted as source 2 in your image of the data, then you probably don't need to use a pivot table for this.

Format your data as a Table. Press Ctrl+T with your cursor anywhere in the data.

Add a new column with a formula to calculate the Max Net Domestic Migration in each state:

```
=MAXIFS([Net Domestic Migration],[State],[@State])
```

I've filtered on MA:
[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pexNr.png)

Now create a column that tests each row to see if it's the same as the Max Net Domestic Migration. You can use this formula:

```
=[@[Max Net Domestic Migration]]=[@[Net Domestic Migration]]
```

Making your table look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xuhwv.png). I've called the column "is max NDR".

You can also combine the formulas and just have one column, like this:

```
=MAXIFS([Net Domestic Migration],[State],[@State])=[@[Net Domestic Migration]]
```

You can then either Filter the table itself or use a Pivot Table filter. So, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Heh0.png) for the Table, or like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SgO1.png) for the Pivot Table.

If you want to return the Nth county in each State, create a named cell by typing in the [Name Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGojR.png)

I've colored the cell green and called the cell "nth_county".

You can calculate the rank of each county's Net Domestic Migration in the table with this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(([@State]=[State])*([@[Net Domestic Migration]]<[Net Domestic Migration]))+1
```

You can then modify it a little to show a TRUE if it matches the value in nth_county:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(([@State]=[State])*([@[Net Domestic Migration]]<[Net Domestic Migration]))+1=nth_county
```

It would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR5C1.png) if I were interested in the first county in each state.

I could change the nth_county cell to be, say, 5, and it would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceq3z.png).

You could then use the "Rank In State" column to filter for the Nth county in either the Table or in a Pivot Table, if you prefer.